# Remove Button on Right-Click Menu Option

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

A "Remove" context menu item is to be shown when the user right-clicks on a button. If the user clicks on the "Remove" option, that button should be removed from its Tile parent container. How would I implement this using Flex 3 and ActionScript 3?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a custom [flash.ui.ContextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenu.html), to which is added a [ContextMenuItem](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/ui/ContextMenuItem.html) corresponding to the **Remove** text that you want the user to select.

Add an event listener to this `ContextMenuItem`, which will handle removing the item clicked.  Here's one way to implement the removal:

```
  private function removeItemHandler(event:ContextMenuEvent):void
  {
    ((event.mouseTarget as DisplayObject).parent as DisplayObjectContainer).removeChild((event.mouseTarget as DisplayObject));
    Alert.show((event.mouseTarget.toString() + " has been removed."),"Display Object Removed");
  }
```

Finally, make sure to set the [contextMenu](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#contextMenu) property of all the components ([InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html)'s) you want to be removable to the custom `ContextMenu` you created.

**Note**

The code of above corresponds to Flex 3, since the question specified that.  For Flex 4, one would use `IVisualElement`, `IVisualElementContainer`, and the `removeElement` method, in place of `DisplayObject`, `DisplayObjectContainer`, and the `removeChild` method, respectively.